# Best way of moving a file from one network to another c# iis

Tags: c#, iis, base64, asmx

I am writing an IIS Web service (in an `asmx` file) using C# that takes a file as an input and moves it to a specific server directory.

What I am currently doing is, I convert this file into a `Base64` string before calling the web service, and pass this `Base64` type string into the web service. Web service converts the string into a file and saves it to the directory.

Is there a better practice ?

Comment: What would be the problem in just passing the byte array?

Comment: You can POST your file without any conversion (with minimal overhead)...

Comment: Just pass the byte array. If the file is too big, use some compression algorithm, such as `gzip`

Comment: @nvoigt there is no problem at all, just asking the best practice.

Comment: @L.B can you please provide an example ?

Comment: @0014 web services (hosted in .asmx) use xml/soap based protocol which means every binary data has to be converted to text (base64, hex string etc. ) either manually or automatically. Use google to find *file upload* samples.....

Comment: @L.B I believe I also am able to pass  `byte[]` to my function. In this case it would be a better idea to just pass the binary data I believe ?

Comment: Normally the data contract serializer should take care of how to represent the binary data.

Comment: @nvoigt the down part of using a `byte[]` would be encountering some issues if I convert the file to binary in a different language let say `Java`. As far as I know the conversion differs from C#. I wont be able to use my web service in other languages.

Comment: @0014 passing byte[] means the framework will do this conversion for you automatically... So it requires less code but you still post a file bigger than the original file

Comment: @L.B thanks for the point

Comment: What do you mean by "convert your file to binary"? A file *is* binary. It's a bunch of bytes.

Comment: @nvoigt I meant converting (or casting, not sure) it into a `byte[]` in both languages. The file is a bunch of bytes but it is represented different in different languages as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As L.B pointed out in the comments that;

> Web services (hosted in .asmx) use xml/soap based protocol which means
>   every binary data has to be converted to text (base64, hex string etc.
>   ) either manually or automatically.

So the best way is what I was doing it from the beginning. Here is the codes that I use;

Converting a file into `Base64` type string;

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("file path");
string file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Converting `Base64` string back into file;

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```